# For xlib, how to create a child window with the background pixel or pixmap of its parent window?

Tags: background, pixel, xlib, pixmap, createwindow

I want to create a child window with the background pixel or pixmap of its parent window. But i can not find refer Xlib API. The workaround I can think of is this: create a child window first, and then use XCopyArea to copy part of parent window. Is there a more direct method?

I searched this question on search engines such as Bing, but couldn't find an answer. Asked this question on chatgpt, and the answer was to use the background_pixel member of XWindowAttributes, or use XQueryColor. This is obviously nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Xlib - C Language X Interface: Background Attribute](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Background_Attribute)

- You can set the *background-pixel* of a window to any pixel value (no default). If you specify a *background-pixel*, it overrides either the default *background-pixmap* or any value you may have set in the *background-pixmap*.
- If you set the *background-pixmap*, it overrides the default.
- If you set the *background-pixmap* to `ParentRelative`:

  - The parent window's *background-pixmap* is used.
  - If the parent window has a *background-pixmap* of `None`, the window also has a *background-pixmap* of `None`.
- Setting a new background, whether by setting *background-pixmap* or *background-pixel*, overrides any previous background.

**Edit:**

According to [Window Attributes](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Window_Attributes), the default value for *background-pixmap* is `None` and for *background-pixel* the value is undefined.

Comment: So it mean that i can create child window with background pixmap of its parent, but can not with background pixel of its parent ? if set child pixmap to None and haven't set pixel, and parent set pixel and haven't set pixmap, then child background will be None (pixmap) or parent's pixel ?

Comment: Only `ParentRelative` has an impact on the child (pixmap, not pixel). If `ParentRelative` is set but the parent pixmap is set to `None`,  then pixmap of the child will also be set to `None`.